# Run a R script from another script and skip rows

Tags: r

I think my question is quite basic, but I was unfortunately not able to find an answer: 
I want to run a script in R Studio and run other quite long scripts (all in the same Project) from it to modify my data.  I think what I need is the `source()` function, but unfortunately I havn't been able to skip rows. 
I want to skip certain rows, or at least the first 14.

Comment: is the file you're sourcing works separately? eg when you execute it in the console?

Comment: @lebelinoz has linked the answer but I I would refactor the code by splitting it into differenent files or even functions if possible (line numbers of the code to call could change and if not it is one more reason to refactor).

Comment: The files (R Scripts you mean?)  work separately, but they have lines to clear the Environment, read in the data again I want to change or create a lot of stuff, I don't need. I didn't expect that it's so difficult.

Comment: Ok, now I can run my script from line X to Y, But I still can't figure out, how I can't skip a certain row inside it.